# strange mvc actionlink behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For some reason my action link behavior sends users to a strange place.

I have two classes: locations and properties.

From the locations view I want a link that leads the users to browse properties in that location:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Browse", "Browse", "Property", new { id=item.ID } )
```

So I would like the HTML link and the method to have the same name: "browse".

Instead of having it in the current controller/view I want to send the ID to the properties controller. Notice the word "Location" does not appear in the line above.

But the URL ends up:

> http://localhost:50164/Location/Browse?Length=8

I want it to end up like this:

> http://localhost:50164/Property/Browse?Length=8

The API in MVC 3 appears to be:

```
ActionLink( "text to display as HTML link", "action name", "controller", "parameters" )
```

Which seems to be how I did it, but I get unexpected results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method signiture `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)`.

It is using the `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)` which has the following parameter names:

```
htmlHelper, linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes
```

Use this method instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Browse", "Browse", "Property", new { id=item.ID }, null)
```

which has the following parameter names:

```
htmlHelper, linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes
```

See [the full list of overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx)

Comment: You'd think with intellisense I would have noticed that fifth parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `null` to the end of your `Html.ActionLink` parameter, otherwise this `length=8` will always try to make you crazy.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Browse", "Browse", "Property", new { id = item.ID }, null)
```